# Is there a way to create an image from a given control in the .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I basically want to be able to say "Hey, control give me your bitmap image." using something like Control.RenderToBitmap or using some code.

The control in question is a panel with various other controls on top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily.  It's probably simplest to just [do a full screen capture](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/03/11/ScreenCaptureInTheCompactFramework.aspx) and then clip that to your control bounds.